# Multi-dimensional array as input with Embedding Layer and LSTM in Keras getting error of dimension in Embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, keras

I have a multidimensional array **X_train** of shape(1000,3,162) like this:

```
    [[[    0     0     0 ...     0     0     0]
      [    0     0     0 ...     0     0     0]
      [22175     0     0 ...     0     0     0]]

      [[    0     0     0 ...     0     0     0]
       [22175     0     0 ...     0     0     0]
       [37363 39010     0 ...     0     0     0]]

     [[22175     0     0 ...     0     0     0]
      [37363 39010     0 ...     0     0     0]
      [31559 42695     0 ...     0     0     0]]

       ...

    [[20651 31559 43650 ...     0     0     0]
     [20651 12733 40329 ...     0     0     0]
     [31559 15394 31559 ...     0     0     0]]]
```

My Model looks like this:

```
      main_input = Input(shape=(162,)) # only pass in the indexes
      emb = Embedding(input_dim=3, output_dim = 162)(main_input)
      doc_output = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False))(emb)
      doc_output = Dense(units=43, activation='softmax')(doc_output)
      model = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=doc_output)
      model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
      print(model.summary())
      history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=1,batch_size=128,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

and I'm getting this error

> Error when checking input: expected input_7 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 3, 162)

Summary of model is here

[image]

How to add this input array to feed it into embedding layer as train and test data is 3-dimensional?

Comment: Can you share the model summary before fitting?

Comment: I have added the summary in the post.

Comment: According to this code, you're only expecting your input layer to get 162 dimensional vectors, this should be changed, that's the reason for shape conflict

Comment: can you guide me how I should change the input layer shape?

Comment: Try changing main_input = Input(shape=(162,)) to 
main_input = Input(shape=(3,162))

Comment: Now I'm getting this error 'nput 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_31: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207667/discussion-between-aizayousaf-and-saurav-joshi).